# NodeJS daemon running on raspbian loads up cpu

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I have a nodeJS script that runs on a raspberryPI and sends ip updates to ddns server. It runs fine if i execute it in bash like "node ddnsupdater.js". But if I install it as service, starts using CPU up to 99% all the time (according to TOP) and doesn't seem to work at all(no updates being sent).

ddnsupdater.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const https = require('https');

var minutes = 5, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 1000;

//Set up update timer
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("I am doing my 5 minutes update");
  updateIP();
}, the_interval);

function updateIP(){
    const options = {
      hostname: 'dynupdate.no-ip.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/nic/update?hostname=' + hostname,
      method: 'GET',
      auth: username+':'+password
    };
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);

  res.on('data', (d) => {       
    console.log('Server response: ' + d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
}

//Run initial update
updateIP();
```

ddnsupdater.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dynamic DNS Updater Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/ddnsupdater/ddnsupdater.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
# Note RHEL/Fedora uses 'nobody', Debian/Ubuntu uses 'nogroup'
Group=nogroup  
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/ddnsupdater

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I still havent figured out a solution for this problem